# Groovy initialization of array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, groovy, initialization

I am looking for the most compact syntax to initialize an array of objects in Groovy.
Given:

```
class Program {
    String id = ""
    String title = ""
    String genre = ""   
}
```

I am currently doing this:

```
Program[] programs = [
    new Program([id:"prog1", title:"CSI", genre:"Drama"]),
    new Program([id:"prog2", title:"NCIS", genre:"Drama"]),
    new Program([id:"prog3", title:"Criminal Minds", genre:"Crime drama"]), 
] as Program[]
```

I seem to recall that in Java there is a more compact syntax, possibly not requiring to use the new keyword. What is the most compact Groovy syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: could you show example of this _more compact syntax_ from Java?

Comment: Ok, memory failed me. It's been a while since I last wrote Java code. The shortened version is indeed only for basic types, not for objects. The shortest I could write in Java does not need to mention the name of the parameters in the call to the constructor, however it still needs the new keyword. I have edited my original post accordingly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Program {
    String id = ""
    String title = ""
    String genre = ""   
}

Program[] programs = [
    ["prog1", "CSI", "Drama"],
    ["prog2", "NCIS", "Drama"],
    ["prog3", "Criminal Minds", "Crime drama"]
]

println programs
```

Please also answer @Igor's question.

Comment: Or you can change `def programs` to `Program[] programs` and get rid of the `as Program[]` at the end :-)

Comment: Yup, makes more sense and less code. Changing right away. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. I also answered Igor's question and edited my original post accordingly.